# dot product issue with np.exp

Tags: python, numpy

I running a simple dot product of y and X (X is Iris dataset) and passing its output into a sigmoid function. When I do this I get the error "loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type float which has no callable exp method". If I remove the line of code that does the dot product and pass in y (instead of y1) I am able to get the code to compile. I don't understand why I would be getting errors for something like this... Especially since y and y1 are of same datatype...

**Failing case**

```
y = np.zeros(4)
print("y shape:",y.shape)
print("X shape:",X.shape)
y1 = np.dot(X,y)
print("y1 shape:",y1.shape)
print("y1 type:",type(y1))
print("y type:",type(y))

1/ (1 +np.exp(y1))
```

OUTPUT

```
y shape: (4,)
X shape: (150, 4)
y1 shape: (150,)
y1 type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
y type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'exp'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-146-06b594f9f80b> in <module>
      8 print("y type:",type(y))
      9 
---> 10 1/ (1 +np.exp(y1))

TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type float which has no callable exp method
```

**Passing case**

```
y = np.zeros(4)
print("y shape:",y.shape)
print("X shape:",X.shape)
#y1 = np.dot(X,y)
#print("y1 shape:",y1.shape)
#print("y1 type:",type(y1))
print("y type:",type(y))

1/ (1 +np.exp(y))
```

OUTPUT

```
y shape: (4,)
X shape: (150, 4)
y type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5])
```

Comment: Tell us about `X`.  What's its `dtype`?  Also what's `y1.dtype`.

Comment: I am not getting this error: np version '1.19.5', Python 3.7.4

Comment: X is the iris dataset

'X.dtype = object
y.dtype = float64
y1.dtype = object

numpy version = 1.19.1
python version = 3.7.3'

Comment: That object dtype is the problem.  `exp` expects a float dtype.  You need to figure out X is object.  I'd also examine the `y1` values.

Comment: yeah when I run .astype(float) it compiles. thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I should have guessed that `astype` would work.  The array is 2d and the `dot` worked (though possibly slowly).  Non-numeric elements would have produced a 1d array, or one that didn't work in `dot` (no plus or times methods).